# NServiceBus: Scatter-Gatherer pattern

Tags: nservicebus

I've searched the web on this topic for NServiceBus but haven't found any
example or solution.

I have a web service which receives a query from a client. The web service
should publish the query to subscribing servers and return the result back to
the web service. The web service aggregates the results before returning it to
the client.

I've run the Full Duplex example but i'm not sure how to make it work for my
scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Kalvin

Comment: It sounds like you want all this to happen within one web request to the web service. Is that so? If so, it's not possible to do that. It seems a little more detail might be helpful.

Comment: Is is required that the response return immediately?  If so, maybe you should consider making each "subscriber" query on a different thread and wait for all the results.  Would it be possible to aggregate the data prior to the query?